# Change size of Bootstrap carousel arrows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

hello am using boostarp 3 bu the size of the control arrows is small, is there a way I can change their size

Comment: can you please put your code and explain what more about it

Answer (score 0):

That is posible to do, inspect the element in your browser and find out what style rule than affects the arrows

Comment: It might be a psudo element like :before or :after